# Submit form and disable submission button

Tags: forms, 8

I want to disable the submit button after it is clicked to prevent multiple submissions. I have:

```
$form['show'] = [
'#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $textforsubmitbutton,
    '#name' => 'submit',
    '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "javascript: this.disabled = true;"
    ),
];
```

but this disabled the button completely. Using "onsubmit" in place of "onclick" doesn't change anything on the button. So maybe I need something like:

```
    '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "javascript: this.submit; this.disabled = true;"
    ),
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using bootstrap - that's where i found the solution finally:

```
'#attributes' => array("onclick" => "
      jQuery(this).addClass('disabled');;
")
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: This solution works perfectly, even handled failed validation on submit and re-enables the button.

Answer (score 6):

For those wanting to disable the form submit button on load, try this:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['disabled']  = 'disabled';
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I was trying to use `['submit']['#disabled'] = TRUE;`.

Comment: And 'hidden' => 'hidden' for whom would like to hide it (even if its not the exact need of this topic, it could help others).

Answer (score 4):

In your context, `this` refers to the submit input element which doesn't have the method `submit()`. You can use some jQuery to disabled the element on click then find the form element to submit.

```
'#attributes' => array("onclick" => "
      jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
      jQuery(this).parents('form').submit();
"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. This works fine for me, although I don't like inlining this piece of js and would move it to a .js file.

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['onclick'][] = "
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!form.reportValidity()) {
    form.reportValidity();
  }
  else {
    jQuery(this).after('<div class=\"ajax-progress ajax-progress-throbber\"><div 
      class=\"throbber\">&nbsp;</div></div>')
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
    jQuery(this).closest('form').submit();
  }
";
```

This adds the default ajax loading icon and disables the submit button. I did that for the  custom Drupal commerce module. Also, this makes the default browser validation work using reportValidity(). Well, except for IE of course.

Answer (score 0):

This might help https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form/issues/3160683

just simply insert drupal/core form JS to prevent the duplication issue.

```php
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.form';
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting a separate JS file to better manage the JS, you can create a library and attach an event.

Add the library to your my_module.libraries.yml file.

```
my_module.disable_on_click:
  version: VERSION
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal.form
    - core/jquery
  js:
    js/my_module_disable_on_click.js: { }
```

Attach the library to your form.

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.disable_on_click';
```

Also add a class to your submit button. (You may wish to append or replace class, whatever you'd prefer).

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['disable-on-click'],
    ],
  ];
```

Now you're free to edit js/my_module_disable_on_click.js how you want. This is mine that disables submit, adds the ajax loading gif and submits the form.

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.disableOnClick = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('.disable-on-click').on('click', function(event) {
        $(event.target).prop('disabled', true);
        let button_text = $(event.target).text();
        $(event.target).html(button_text + ' <img src="/core/misc/throbber-active.gif">');
        $(event.target).parents('form').submit();
      });

    }
  };

}(jQuery));
```